# How can I call/use my scope in my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, has-many-through, has-scope

I am trying to use has_scope to filter all Keys that are not connected to a Room via my KeyRoomMapping Table.

I've created the scope in my Keys model, but I don't know how to call the scope in my view.

**Models**

```
class Key < ApplicationRecord  

  has_many :key_room_mappings, foreign_key: :key_id, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :rooms, through: :key_room_mappings

  ###Is this the best way to find all Keys that are not connected to a room?
  scope :without_rooms, -> { where.not(id: KeyRoomMapping.distinct.pluck(:key_id)) }

end

class KeyRoomMapping < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :room
  belongs_to :key

end

class Room < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :key_room_mappings, foreign_key: :room_id, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :keys, through: :key_room_mappings

end
```

**Controller**

```
class KeysController < ApplicationController

  has_scope :without_rooms

  def index
    @keys = apply_scopes(Key).all
  end

end
```

**View**

```
###How can I use my scope to filter my list below, this is not working...
<%= link_to "Keys Without Rooms", {controller: 'keys', action: 'index', without_rooms: ''} %>

  <% @keys.each do |key| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= key.name %></td>
      <td><%= key.copy %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: BTW, `where.not(id: KeyRoomMapping.select(:key_id))` would use a subquery (`where id not in (select key_id ...)`) which should be faster than pulling all the distinct values out of the database and then sending back in with a separate query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `boolean` option to `has_scope`, which you'll use while building the path:

```
# controller
has_scope :without_rooms, type: :boolean

# view
link_to "Keys Without Rooms", '/keys?without_rooms=true' # or keys_path(without_rooms: true)
```

Comment: Well i would like has_scope so that I can show All Keys first, then allow the user to click the link as a way to filter it down to Keys Without Rooms...

Comment: Is there a way to show All Keys to start, then allow Key.without_rooms to be a filtered via the link in the view?

Comment: @SurgePedroza I have edited the answer, even though I do not think it is the best you can get..

Comment: This works, thanks! If you have any other suggestion feel free to share.

Comment: @SurgePedroza You're welcome! I just didn't read carefully the question from the first time, so nevermind the first part of the answer :)